# Testing the diagonalizability of matrix $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\lambda_1 &a&b\\0&\lambda_1 & c\\0&0& \lambda_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

How to show that the matrix

$$B= \left(\begin{array}(\lambda_1 & a & b \\ 0 & \lambda_1 & c\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_2\end{array}\right)$$

is diagonalizable when $a\neq0$, when $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$. How should I work this out? I tried comparing the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues of $B$ but I didn't succeed in this approach yet.

Comment: This assumes that $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I will add this to the task.

Comment: You mean it's **not** diagonalizable when $a \ne 0$, and diagonalizable when $a = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to note that $B - \lambda_1 I$ has nullity (null-space dimension) $1$ when $a \neq 0$ and $2$ when $a = 0$.  So, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_1$ is $1$ when $a \neq 0$ and $2$ when $a = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was on the right track then. Sry for my simple questions, I'm still learning the subject ;)

Comment: The fact that your questions admit a satisfactory, quick answer is not a sign that your questions are inherently simple; the way I see it, it means that you're asking exactly the right questions and doing the work in between on your own.  Good luck!

Comment: Nice to hear that. Appreciate it and thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, when the dimension is $3$ and the repeated diagonal entries appear only in contiguous blocks, the problem is not really destabilizing.

The case when the dimension is $n$ is studied in [If a matrix is triangular, is there a quicker way to tell if it is can be diagonalized?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558591/if-a-matrix-is-triangular-is-there-a-quicker-way-to-tell-if-it-is-can-be-diagon/1559880#1559880)

When the repeated diagonal entries appear only in contiguous blocks, the matrix $B$ is similar to the matrix of diagonal blocks; here $B$ is similar to $diag(\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&a\\0&\lambda_1\end{pmatrix},\lambda_2)$. Thus $B$ is diagonalizable iff each block is diagonal; consequently, the complexity of this algorithm is $0$ algebraic operation.

The case when the equal eigenvalues are not grouped is much more difficult. We have not been able to find an algorithm that does the job in $O(n^2)$ and even in $o(n^3)$.

Who can do better?